# YouTube app on iPad 1 stopped working again (Error : App is out dated)

Tags: ipad, applications, youtube

The YouTube app on my iPad 1 has stopped working. It shows an error: `Error: App is Outdated`.

How do I get the app to work again?

Comment: which iOS version and which version of the YouTube app are installed on your iPad? Can you still access YouTube in Safari?